# The workspace already exists for you on this computer or another JetBrains WebStorm

Tags: tfs, webstorm, tfvc

I'm working in Linux Mint 19 & using JetBrains. I have Team Foundation Server 2015 Update 4 installed on premise by my company whenever I try to checkout a project from the TFS I'm getting this message:

> The workspace 'SmartGPS_Git' already exists for you on this computer
>   or another. Please try checking out the repository again with a
>   different unique directory name.

TEE CLC tool is configured in JetBrains WebStorm.

I tried to

- Uninstall JetBrains WebStorm & reinstall it
- remove TEE CLC tool with no luck
- `tf workspace /server:http://{TFSServername}:8080/tfs/{CollectionName} /delete “{workspacename};{owner}”`  it didn't even work

On Windows you can remove any workspace with the Visual Studio but here I don't have Visual Studio.

Comment: Use TEE command line to update the workspace, delete the workspace and recreate it, or create a brand new workspace. If you don't know how to use TEE, look at the documentation for it.

Answer (score 0):

Please try to use `/collection` instead of /server to delete the workspace, the command should look like:

```
workspace   /delete [/collection:<url>] [<workspacename;[workspaceowner]>]
```

Also, you can try to create a new workspace to see whether the issue persists:

```
 workspace   /new [/noprompt] [/template:<value>] [/computer:<value>] [/comment:<value>|@valuefile]
              [/collection:<url>] [/location:server|local] [/filetime:current|checkin]
              [/permission:Private|PublicLimited|Public] [<workspacename;[workspaceowner]>]
```